# JSF / Primefaces: Pre Select an option in a OneMenu

Tags: jsf, selected, selectonemenu

I have a simple OneMenu in JSF:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProductBean {
  ...
  protected static Map<String, String> priceTypes;
  ...
  getter & setter
}

<p:selectOneMenu id="sizeType" >
  <f:selectItems value="#{productBean.priceTypes}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

In my usecase, i want to preselect[1] an option out of "priceTypes" - how can i do that?

I am using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 with Primefaces 3.4.1

[1] See "selected" at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about pfaces, but in plain JSF you just have to set the `value` attribute in the `selectOneMenu` tag, and make sure that the value returned by the bean is in the select list.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="sizeType" value="#{myBean.sizeType}>
  <f:selectItems value="#{productBean.priceTypes}" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Of course, `sizeType` must mutch the key of your map.

Comment: ...and just make sure that your `@PostConstruct` method initializes the suggested `sizeType` to your default choice.

Comment: That's it, thank you (to be clear: also works with primefaces)!